# Считывание клавиш в консоли на linux, модуль pynput

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, input, клавиатура

Оказывается на Linux нет модуля `getch`, я нашёл альтернативу `pynput`. Я почитал документацию, примерно понял как работает, потестировал, но вопрос: как мне соединиться с `listener`, а в дальнейшем использовать проверку клавиш в отдельной функции, которая находится в цикле. В двух словах проверять нажатие в цикле `while True:`

```
from pynput import keyboard

def on_press(key):
    try:
        print('alphanumeric key {0} pressed'.format(
            key.char))
    except AttributeError:
        print('special key {0} pressed'.format(
            key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} released'.format(
        key))
    if key == keyboard.Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

# Collect events until released
with keyboard.Listener(
        on_press=on_press,
        on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Понимаю глупость моего кода, но что поделать?

Comment: а чем не устраивает документация по этому модулю? https://pynput.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

Comment: @strawdog, да вроде как читаю, но реализовать не могу

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Подозреваю (сильно), что на самом деле Ваш вопрос должен звучать так:

Как мне написать программу, что бы она всё время слушала клавиатуру, а пока ничего не нажимается, шла фоновая работа?

Ответ на этот вопрос стандартен: надо создать отдельную нитку (thread) в которой и будет выполнятся код, который Вы привели в примере, а в основной программе в это время будет делаться что-то другое.

Comment: Вы всё верно подозревали, именно это и надо было мне